process ID of process launched with system command
Suppose I open a shell on ubuntu OS, then open a software such as matlab via
matlab &

In the matlab GUI, I do a system command
system('/path/to/my/cppprog') % <-- PID of this running program?

where I launch a self written c++ program called 'cppprog'
Now, I want to figure out the process ID associated with the program that I launched. How can I do it? I may invoke multiple system commands of the same program with different command-line arguments.

I didn't know pidof existed. That's what you want.  My answer was exactly what it output's, by default.  Thanks for the heads up, @arielmarcovitch.

As @Kusalananda suggested, pgrep myprog lists all running instances of myprog. /proc/mypid/cmdline helps to uniquely find a process if several instances of myprog are alive.

pgrep firefox gives me a single PID.  pidof firefox shows 18 different PID's.

@simon you can use pgrep -f "full command" instead of going through /proc/*/cmdline

@arielmarcovitch This comment seems to be the best answer to to my question. Because what I do in matlab is system("full command"). Hence, pgrep -f "full command"gives me this corresponding PID.

I'm assuming here you mean getting the pid from a shell, and not from your matlab script.
You can see all children of your matlab script like this:
matlab &
pstree -ap $!

$! is the pid of the last command you run in the background. If it is not the last, either find the pid of matlab with pidof matlab or just use $$ which is the pid of the current shell, to show all descendants of your shell, including those of matlab

Would it not be more efficient to use pgrep?  This seems to be an instance of "I know the name of my process, and now I need to find its PID", which is what pgrep does for you.

@ariel marcovitch I do not want to query the PID from the shell. Basically, I run some c++ executables launched via a system command in the matlab gui, and want to reliably identify the PID of the thus created processes? What I know is the name of the executable (cppprog in the example above) as well as the command line arguments. With this information, I have to query the PID.

@simon So this is a matlab question really, right? If so, I will remove my answer and let people who actually know matlab answer it. Just add a matlab tag to your question. As far as I read, you can't easily get the pid of your children, which means you probably need to run system with the mentioned command... I'm not sure how to get the results of the system commands into matlab, though... Sorry I'm unable to help here
